# errorBody with retrofit2 and kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit2, response, http-status-code-500

I am trying to get the error returned by a service (when starting with invalid credentials) rest api but for some reason errorBody does not catch it from my answer.

The correct answer I receive without problems but when I get an error I can't solve what the server sends me.

Sorry for my English, I had to use the translator

This is the part where I should get the error

```
override fun postLogin(callback: OperationCallBack<ResponseToken>, user: Login) {
    call = Api.build()?.login(user)
    call?.enqueue(object :Callback<ResponseToken>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseToken>, t: Throwable) {
            callback.onError(t.message)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseToken>, response: Response<ResponseToken>) {
            Log.v(TAG, "ErrorMensaje: ${response.message()}")
            Log.v(TAG, "ErrorBodyToString: ${response.errorBody().toString()}")

            response.body()?.let {
                if(response.isSuccessful && (it.isSuccess())){
                    Log.v(TAG, "token ${it.token}")
                    callback.onSuccess(it)
                }else{
                    Log.v(TAG, "token ${it.token}")
                    callback.onError("Error ocurrido")
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

errorBody shows me only with toString otherwise it returns null. With toString this is what I get

```
2020-06-10 19:26:05.095 26590-26590/com.umbani.umbani V/CONSOLE: ErrorMensaje:
2020-06-10 19:26:05.095 26590-26590/com.umbani.umbani V/CONSOLE: ErrorBodyToString: okhttp3.ResponseBody$Companion$asResponseBody$1@fcb3843
```

The okHttp console shows the error as it comes from the server, which I cannot catch

```
D/OkHttp: {"success":true,"error":{"message":"Invalid credentials"}}
```

It is not a problem to convert with Gson or another converter. I can do that. I have done so with the positive response.

I have seen many answers on StackOverFlow and none has helped me.
Thank you

**UPDATE:**
I found the solution in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55835083/10372439

**SOLUTION:**

Replace `toString ()` to `string ()`

```
response.errorBody()!!.string()
```

Comment: saved my day for telling just ."string()". for those who wants to know , when you're received 404 or 400 error code , you should use errorBody() not body().

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the onFailure block, then cast it with the right object

```
override fun onFailure(call: Call< ResponseToken >, t: Throwable) {
         if (t is HttpException) {
            try {
                val errorStringRaw: String? = t.response()?.errorBody()?.string()
                //Parse error message; format is api specific; we can't make a generic approach for this as of the moment
                val type = object : TypeToken<ResponseBody?>() {}.type
                val response: ResponseBody = Gson().fromJson(errorStringRaw, type)
                } catch (e: Exception) {

                }
         }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work, in fact I have put a Log inside the onFailure and it doesn't enter the method @steven0529

Comment: Check the status code response. Maybe it sends you a STATUS 200 thus Retrofit considers it to be a successful response

Comment: May be try moving the parsing logic from this answer just after `Log.v(TAG, "ErrorBodyToString: ${response.errorBody().toString()}")` for testing purpose.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I do but printing errorBody.toString() does not return the message coming from the server. Only what I put above.

Is there a clear and orderly way to catch errors with retrofit2 when they are not 200?